# Make element with position: absolute stretch the shadow of parent?

Tags: html, css

I have a usual search as most websites do. The results are shown below on the div that is visually connected to the search input.
It looks like this:

[image]

I need to have one solid shadow for the div parent but can't figure out or find online the way to do this.

I thought that I could either make 2 separate shadows, but that will look inconsistent and just terrible. Or I could make a div below with the same height and width that will act as a shadow but that's a non-necessary complication + the .search-results div's height will change dynamically.

This is an example:

```css
body {
  background-color: gray;
}

.search-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin: 100px 100px 0px 100px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: initial;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
.search {
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
} .search input {
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #022222;
  border: none;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
}

.search-results {
  position: absolute;
  height: 150px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: black;
 }
```

```html
<div class="search-wrapper">
  <div class="search">
    <input placeholder="air max . . .">
  </div>
  <div class="search-results">
  
  </div>
</div>
```

I am sure there must be a clever and simple way to do this.

Please help,

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need to use positions here and you can use FlexBox instead. It's the best way and a lot easier. Also, you can ignore all of them, they will place on top of each other because they are block-level tags/elements. (divs)
2. You don't need to put the input in another div parent, use it as I did.

Sorry, I couldn't understand your code, so I must write the whole code from the beginning.

> **EDIT**

I removed display flex, cause it's not necessary.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Arial;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #fff
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 30px
}

.search-wrapper {
  /* EDITED HERE ADDED HEIGHT */
  position: relative;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 200px;
  height: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 5px rgba(232, 232, 232, .2)
}

.search-input {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  
  padding-block: 5px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 15px
}

.search-result {
  /* EDITED HERE */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: .5px
}

p {
  padding: 10px 0 10px 10px;
}

p:hover {
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<div class='search-wrapper'>
  <input class='search-input' placeholder='Search...'>
  <div class='search-result'>
    <p>Nike Airforce</p>
    <p>Nike Airforce</p>
    <p>Nike Airforce</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: position absolute is extremely important because it will be on top of other elements that are on the page. If position is not set to "absolute", then it will constantly moving all the elements above up and down

Comment: You know when you must apply position absolute? Position absolute must be in Position relative. if you want the search wrapper to be on top of other elements, set the position of the wrapper to relative and the z-index to 999. I edited the code.

Comment: thank for the reply. From what you did the .search-result still won't be on top of the elements because it's not set to position absolute. And if you set it to position absolute - then all the box-shadow will be messed up. Be "on top of the elements below" means this:
https://www.amazon.com/
if you start typing something in the search box - the "search-results" will be "on top" of the other content

Comment: if you have a look here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position
You can see that position relative still takes up the space of it's original positioning. Although, it is moved to the side

Comment: I edited the code, please tell me it works.